# Retrieving items that are stored as variables from Python modules that are also stored as variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables, module

I am using import_module to import multiple python modules as variables in a loop. Then, within each loop, I have different dictionaries that I need to retrieve. I have each of these dictionaries stored as variables as well. See the example below. I am running into an issue on the line with `vals = test_file.item.get("text")` because test_file has no attribute named item.

Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
from importlib import import_module

file_list = ['file1','file2']
dict_list = ['test1','test2']

for file in file_list:
  test_file = import_module(file)
  for item in dict_list:
    vals = test_file.item.get("text")
```

file1:

```
test1 = {
  'text':['example1','example2','example3']
  }
test2 = {
  'text':['example1','example2','example3']
  }
```

file2:

```
test1 = {
  'text':['example1','example2','example3']
  }
test2 = {
  'text':['example1','example2','example3']
  }
```

How can I access my dictionary that is stored as a variable from my file that is also stored as a variable?

Sorry if this is a repost. I had trouble searching for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `getattr` on the module.

```
from importlib import import_module

file_list = ['file1','file2']
dict_list = ['test1','test2']

for file in file_list:
    test_file = import_module(file)
    for item in dict_list:
        # getattr will return the attributes (test1, test2)
        # from the module instance which you can then call .get() on
        vals = getattr(test_file, item).get("text")
        print(vals)
```

To check for membership of the attribute first you could call the associated `hasattr`.

Comment: Thank you! I have less than 15 reputation so I cannot record an upvote for your answer, but I really appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem. You should be able to mark it as accepted although I'm not certain.

Comment: I can and I did. Thank you.